# Allowing Python To Access The Program Files Folder With Admin Permissions

Tags: python, directory, admin, permission-denied

I've got this program that copies all the files out of a folder called `src` and creates a directory called `C:\Program Files\my_program` then pastes them in it. Next, it creates a shortcut in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` For the executable in `C:\Program Files\my_program`. I've used the `ctypes` library
and this "prompt" thing to gain admin access to the program: `ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", "python", "my_program.py", None, 1) <= 32`.
But it doesn't work, it returns this error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files'`.

Here's my code so far:

```
from winshell import Shortcut
import os
import shutil
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", "python", "my_program.py", None, 1) <= 32

cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
full_cwd = cwd.replace("\\", "\\")

source_folder = full_cwd + "\\src"
destination_folder = "C:\\Program Files\\my_program"

if not os.path.exists(destination_folder):
    os.makedirs(destination_folder)

for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(source_folder, filename), destination_folder)

shortcut_path = os.path.join("C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs", "my_program.lnk")
shortcut = Shortcut(path=shortcut_path)

shortcut.path = os.path.join(destination_folder, "my_program.exe")
shortcut.working_directory = destination_folder
shortcut.icon_location = (os.path.join(destination_folder, "icon.ico"), 0)
shortcut.description = "my_program"

shortcut.show_cmd = Shortcut.SW_HIDE

shortcut.save()
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?